# Looking for data structure

Tags: java, data-structures

Looking for data structure which would have these properties:

1. Fixed size (like an `Array`).
2. Cannot contain same elements (like `HashSet`).
3. Ability to remove element from any position (like `E remove(int i)` in `ArrayList`).
4. Set element in any position, but only if it is empty, otherwise throw an exception.

Is there such data structure? Or I need to implement myself?

Comment: So you want it fixed-size... but with the ability to remove or add elements?!

Comment: Why don't you create your own class to do all this?

Comment: You do see he said he could do that... he's just asking for a more efficient solution. Yeesh

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. He specified criteria for a data structure and asks if it exists or if he needs to write it himself. The question is clear, simple, and has a definitive answer.

Comment: @Tunaki He doesn't want to add or remove elements, he wants to add or remove elements "from a given position". In other words, what an array does.

Comment: @nhouser9 *Add element to any position, but only if it is empty*. How can you do that without changing the size?

Comment: @nhouser9 Because #3 is conflicting with #1, so nothing clear or simple about that. #3 doesn't say "clear the value at given index", it says "like remove(int i) in ArrayList". So not the same thing!

Comment: I don't believe there is any existing off-the-shelf data structure that does this for you, but you could create this out of a combination of a regular array and a `HashSet` tracking what elements have already been added so far.

Comment: @Tunaki It is very easy to do. Just have an array of nulls. On add, check for null in the specified position. If there is a null, replace it with the element being added. If there is not a null, throw an exception.

Comment: That's not adding an element, that's setting an element. Conversely, setting to `null` isn't removing an element "like `remove(int i)` in `ArrayList`". If this is what the OP is asking, a simple array does this already, like you said.

Comment: @Tunaki Clearly wrong. An array does not satisfy 2 or 4. So just to be clear, your downvotes are based on the fact that OP has a slight confusion between the definitions of "adding" and "setting" and element? That's really enough to make the question unclear / unsalvageable?

Comment: @nhouser9 Yes. Feel free to edit the question and clarify it if you think you understood what the OP really wants. So far, they didn't respond to any comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a class with an `T []` and a `HashSet<T>`. If the `HashSet` contains the element to be added, it's a duplicate. If the `T []` has a non-null (or whatever you flag), that element is occupied. To remove, you'd need to remove from both data structures. The size can be limited through the `T []`.

With this all the 4 operations would be `O(1)` time.

Comment: Why `HashMap` and not `HashSet`? What is the map value used for?

Comment: @Andreas true... I thought that it would have been useful for some reason (maybe removing by value instead of index).

Comment: So your answer to the questions *"Is there such data structure? Or I need to implement myself?"* is "**No** and **Yes**"? If so, maybe you should actually *answer* the questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `Arrays.asList`:

- This is a fixed-size data structure, backed by an array.
- You can set elements to null, using `list.set(i, null)`
- You can check if an element is contained in the list already, using `list.contains(element)`. This will check the contents linearly; I'm assuming that the list is going to be pretty small, so this is fine in practice.

For example:

```
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(new Integer[5]);

// Unset the value in the second slot, if it is non-null.
if (ints.get(2) != null) {
  ints.set(2, null);
}

// Add 123 to the first slot which is null.
if (!ints.contains(123)) {
  ints.set(ints.indexOf(null), 123);
}
```